# Union - Same table, excluding previous results MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that will:

- Run a query, give me (x) number of rows (limit 4)
- If that query didn't give me the 4 I need, run a second query limit 4-(x) and exclude the ids from the first query
- A third query that acts like the second

I have this:

```
(SELECT *, 1 as SORY_QUERY1 FROM xbamZ where state = 'Minnesota' and industry = 'Miscellaneous' and id != '229' limit 4) 
UNION 
(SELECT *, 2 FROM xbamZ where state = 'Minnesota' limit 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT *, 3 FROM xbamZ where industry = 'Miscellaneous' limit 1)
```

How (or is?) do I do that? Am I close? This query gives me duplicates

Comment: Please have a go at formatting the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no need for union and three `select`s. One will work as well

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
(
SELECT xbamZ.*,
CASE 
  WHEN state = 'Minnesota' and industry = 'Miscellaneous' and id != '229' THEN 1
  WHEN state = 'Minnesota' THEN 2
  WHEN industry = 'Miscellaneous' THEN 3
END as rnk
FROM xbamZ 
where state = 'Minnesota' or industry = 'Miscellaneous' 
)a 
ORDER BY rnk
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I am looking for. Will accept as soon as I can.